# Apache Redirect Problem

Tags: php, redirect

Ive a strange problem, Im getting referals from a website and the site is calling a url that is not avaliable

Code:
http://nzbuse.net/udnc.html/img/logo.jpg

Ive tried to redirect by .htaccess, errordocument and php script but non seem to work.

When my index.php page loads it includes javascript and css, the site also uses smarty.

With a clear cache in firefox, when I goto the the url above I get the following log entries :

"GET /udnc.html/img/logo.jpg HTTP/1.1" 302 213
"GET /missing.php HTTP/1.1" 200 81
"GET /js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1341
"GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 33734
"GET /css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 200 6102
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 26694

But when one of the referals goes to the url they get :

"GET /udnc.html/img/logo.jpg HTTP/1.1" 302 213
"GET /missing.php HTTP/1.1" 200 81

and they dont issue / get the last 4 get requests.

Ive looked all over the net and cant seem to find the answer.

When a user goes to root url they seem to be ok.

The site is for Nzb Files and the users from the redirect dont event browse, I get 1000 plus referals a day and they all do the same thing which is leading me to think there is an issue ?

Anybody any ideas why ?

Regards

Potman

Comment: You should not reply with a 302 when you want to express a 404.

Comment: Hi<br>
The missing.php has the following line<br>
<br>
header( 'Location: /index.html',FALSE,302);
<br>
which is rewritten in the .htaccess file as part of the smarty system, index.php.
<br><br>
Do I need to change it ?
<br>
Thanks<br>
Potman

Answer (score 0):

The last four requests will only be made if an actual browser is being used. An automated tool will catch the 200 on `/missing.php` and be done with the request.

Comment: Hi

Thanks for the fast responce, but it does the same if I use as rewrite in the .htaccess file

RewriteRule ^/udnc\.html/img/logo\.jpg$ index.php [L,R=301]

Would the rewrite not be tranparent and as the index.php needs the external refences force them to load ?

Regards

Potman

Comment: You cannot "force" a client to load anything. It will load whatever it deems necessary. A client that doesn't speak JavaScript probably won't load scripts. A client that doesn't use CSS probably won't load stylesheets. And unless it's a browser, it probably won't load the favicon.

Comment: Hi Again
Just seems strange that clients that load the root url browse the site but clients that come in from the failed url dont. I get a lot more referals (1000 plus a day) than clients that use the root url.
Thanks for your help